# DNOA Errors only on Live Production Servers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I'm having a problem with the login process that only happens on the live servers which is making solving this issue pretty awkward.  I'm also slightly concerned as to why this only seems to happen on the live servers as well as the issue itself.

I have three instance of the system, I develop in Visual Studio and use IISExpress for dev and debugging, I also have a faux "staging" instance which I use a local SSL protected IIS web site and then I have the live production environment at me web hosting company in a virtual dedicated server.

I only seen this problem on the hosted version in the VDS.

The site consists of an MVC4 web site and an OAuth protected API hosted in a separate IIS site on the servers.

**The problem**

When logging into the production site it seems to hiccup during the login process and presents the user with the login screen twice.  One clicking login again the user is logged in properly.

**DNOA Error Message**

DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: Unexpected OAuth authorization response received with callback and client state that does not match an expected value.

**Code - AccountController**

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && SecurityClient.Login(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe))
    {
        ObtainApiOAuthTokens(model.Email, returnUrl);
    }
}

public void ObtainMoodexApiOAuthTokens(string userName, string returnUrl)
{
    var scopes = SecurityClient.GetOauthScopesForCurrentUser(userName);
    _client.GetAuthorised(scopes, returnUrl);
}
```

**Code - APIClient**

```
public void GetAuthorised(IEnumerable<string> scopes, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {
        var nvc = new NameValueCollection { { "returnUrl", returnUrl } };
        RequestUserAuthorization(scopes, new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenCallbackUrl"] + nvc.ToQueryString(false)));
    }
    else
    {
        RequestUserAuthorization(scopes, new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenCallbackUrl"]));
    }
}
```

**Code - AccountController - ReadTokens**

```
public ActionResult ReadTokens()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]))
    {
        try
        {
            IAuthorizationState authorization = _client.ProcessUserAuthorization();
            authorization.Callback = new Uri(authorization.Callback.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization.AccessToken))
            {
                _client.SaveState(authorization);
            }
        }
        catch (ProtocolException ex)
        {
            _log.Fatal("Error reading security tokens", ex);
        }
    }

    string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);
    if (roles.Contains(AppRole.LicenseManager.ToString()))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("index", "licenseadmin", new { @area = "licensemanager" });
    }

    var returnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("index", "dashboard");
    }

    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

Since I apply the `[Authorize]` attribute to the global filters collection all methods that aren't explicitly "opened" using the `[AllowAnonymous]` required the user (request) to be authenticated.  Since the `ReadTokens` callback is executed within the context of the initial `Login` request is it safe to assume that this is why the user is being redirected back to the `Login` view?  Since the response hasn't been sent back to the client the request isn't yet authenticated.

What is the best way to solve this?  Also, if this is the root cause of the issue why would this only appear when using the production instance of the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness on this question.  I eventually tracked down the issue.  When I was deploying to the production servers I had neglected to add an `XML` transformation making certain changes to the configuration file.

All other browsers seemed to operate without any hitch yet Chrome didn't return the authentication cookie reliably in subsequent requests.

After adding in a transformation to set the `domain` attribute (eg: `.example.com`) on the cookie the problems with Chrome vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, check that the clock on your production server is correct.

Comment: Ahhhh OK, will check that.